# Create a custom deque class without appendleft method, inheriting from collections.deque

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

I only want to have append method in my custom deque class.

I have tried this:

```
from collections import deque

del deque.appendleft

class CustomDeque(deque):
     pass
```

But I get the following error:

```
----> 3 del deque.appendleft
      4
      5 class CustomDeque(deque):

TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type 'collections.deque'
```

I would like to get this behavior:

```
>>> custom_deque = CustomDeque()

>>> custom_deque.appendleft()

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)

----> 1 custom_deque.appendleft()

AttributeError: 'CustomDeque' object has no attribute 'appendleft'
```

Comment: Why don't you just use the existing `deque` class and *not use* the `appendleft` method?

Comment: @mkrieger1 I think it is better not to let the programmer have the possibility to do it, we are human and we can make mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option (with a different, possibly more fitting, error):

```
from collections import deque

class CustomDeque(deque):
    def appendleft(self, item):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

You can, of course, raise an `AttributeError`, too, but that would only get raised when the method is actually called. If you really want to hide the attribute, you would have to override `__getattribute__`.

```
class CustomDeque(deque):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == "appendleft":
            raise AttributeError
        return super().__getattribute__(name)
```

Now, both the pure attr lookup and the attempted function call raise the error:

```
>>> c = CustomDeque()
>>> c.appendleft
# ...
AttributeError

>>> c.appendleft()
# ...
AttributeError

>>> hasattr(c, "appendleft")
False
```

Note, however, that appending to the left is still possible via:

```
c.insert(0, ...)
```

Comment: Thanks! 
It was a hypothetical case, in that case I would disable all relationed methods to use it as a FIFO or LIFO only. Because we don't have a strict FIFO/LIFO built-in implementation in Python

Comment: It may be easier then to make your custom class not inherit from deque, but use it as some protected attribute, and just add the methods you want. Whitelisting seems more transparent than blacklisting ;)